# Excel VBA - Macros executing before previous finish

Tags: excel, vba

I realize versions of this question have been asked before, however it doesn't help my case. I have a "final" macro that calls and runs multiple different macro steps:

```
Sub FinalResultsRefresh()

Call RefreshRawData 'Refresh the data sheet query connection
Call DataFillConcatenate 'Run the concatenate macro after the data refreshes for the subheader "CONCAT" column
Call SkuExceptions 'Run the Sku Exceptions Macro
Call ProductTypeExceptions 'Run the Product Type Exceptions Macro
Call FilterDataByCellValue 'Run the filter data by cell value for filters prompt box results
Call DeleteHiddenRows 'Run the delete hidden rows macro to finalize filters
Call Copy 'Run the "Copy" final refresh Macro
Call BoldIt 'Run the BoldIt macro to bold all subheaders


MsgBox "Refresh complete", vbInformation, "Results refresh macro"
End Sub
```

I think the macros are running without finishing the previous one; in this case, my "DeleteHiddenRows" macro executes and moves on to the next macro before it actually deletes the hidden records.

```
Sub DeleteHiddenRows()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow
Set sht = Sheets("Data")
LastRow = sht.UsedRange.Rows(sht.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
For i = LastRow To 1 Step -1
If Rows(i).Hidden = True Then Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
Next

End Sub
```

The delete macro takes about 10 seconds before it actually deletes the records; im assuming even though it "ran" the macro, it didnt have a sufficient amount of time to delete the records before moving on. Is there a way to fix this?

I have tried adding `Sleep 10000` and `Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))` to delay the next macro from moving on until the rows were deleted, however that didn't work.

Comment: In `RefreshRawData` are all of the queries set to not run in the background?  Likewise are there any other asynchronous processes kicked off in the other methods called before `DeleteHiddenRows`  ?

Comment: Are you sure _DeleteHiddenRows_ works right worksheet? `Rows(i)` refers to the active sheet.

Comment: I agree with @Shrotter - you should fix the 'Rows' line first before worrying about timing issues. Try `If sht.Rows(i).Hidden Then sht.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete` so that the code is operating on 'sht' rather than on whatever happens to be the ActiveSheet (also `= True` is redundant). I also guess you are not using `Option Explicit` as you don't define `i` which could be hiding other problems in your code.

Comment: @JohnM I would have never seen that, of course that did the trick! Brilliant.

Comment: Sleep and (as I understand it) Application.Wait are both app-level commands that stop all app-level processing. As such, they're not likely to help when two app-level processes get out of synch.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg yeah I figured since it stopped all processing that was the case. Thanks for clarification!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Further to the comment from @Shrotter - you should fix the 'Rows' line first before worrying about timing issues - use

```
If sht.Rows(i).Hidden Then sht.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
```

so that the code is operating on 'sht' rather than on whatever happens to be the ActiveSheet (also `= True` is redundant). I also guess you are not using `Option Explicit` as you don't define `i` which could be hiding other problems in your code

Answer (score 0):

Well, I certainly have experienced the same sort of thing many many times, and I'm convinced that either VBA is faster than Excel, or that calls are returning before work is complete, as you suggested.

In my debugging, I use a lot of debug.print statements to track what's going on, and have demonstrated this several times.

I'd like to suggest that you write a routine to put in between DeleteHiddenRows and Copy to confirm that all of the hidden rows have actually been deleted before you copy.

I also noticed that in your code as well as in your "wait" code that you aren't calling DoEvents.  You should be calling do events after every line of code that does something to the data in the spreadsheet, although that didn't always solve my problems.

The only way I ended up solving some of my problems was to create global semaphores (global Boolean variables).  Set the semaphore to false before calling one of your routines, and then set the semaphore to true inside the routine when it is done, making sure I called DoEvents before setting the semaphore to true.

I know that global variables aren't considered appropriate in object-oriented code, but if VBA or Excel isn't working properly you might not have any choice.

After rereading my answer, I suspect that DoEvents will be your best option.

Comment: Please let me know if any of my solutions work.  If not, I will continue to investigate.  This issue has been a thorn in my side for a long time and I'd like to get it resolved finally.